# Empty "LIKE" query with non-Latin letters in Live Search with Firebird and Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, autocomplete, firebird, firebird1.5

I am working on live search with jQuery UI autocomplete and CI 3.1.5. It works fine with MySQL, but with Firebird 1.5 I have an empty array. The problem is in my like query.

**Here is my code:**

```
public function get_autocomplete($search_data)
{   
    $this->db1->select('NAME');
    $this->db1->like('NAME', $search_data);
    return $this->db1->get('CLIENTS', 10)->result();
}
```

**I also tried this:**

```
public function get_autocomplete($search_data)
{   

        $query = $this->db1->query("select cl.name
            from clients cl
            where cl.name like '%$search_data%'");

         return $query->result();
}
```

The result is again, an empty array. If I don't use LIKE, my query returns 10 results fine. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Firebird 1.5 works with containing. This code works with English:

```
$query = $this->db1->query("select cl.name
    from clients cl
    where (cl.name containing  '$search_data')");
```

I just tried with MySQL (with like query) table is with charset utf-8 and Collation-utf8_general_ci and I have the same problem - English works, Cyrillic don't. I just tried with pure php and it works in English and Cyrillic. So the **problem** is in ***Codeigniter settings***?

**Here is my database configurations:**

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
   'dsn'   => '',
   'hostname' => '*****',
   'username' => '****',
   'password' => '',
   'database' => 'bulvestprint_mysql',
   'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
   'dbprefix' => '',
   'pconnect' => FALSE,
   'db_debug' => TRUE,
   'cache_on' => FALSE,
   'cachedir' => '',
   'char_set' => 'utf8',
   'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
   'swap_pre' => '',
   'encrypt' => FALSE,
   'compress' => FALSE,
   'stricton' => FALSE,
   'failover' => array(),
   'save_queries' => TRUE
 );

$db['firebird'] = array(
    'dsn'      =>  '',
    'hostname' => 'LOCALHOST',
    'username' => '******',
    'password' => '******',
    'database' => 'D:\Firebird_1_5\BULVEST_SPAS.GDB',
    'dbdriver' => 'ibase',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'WIN1251', //беше NONE
    'dbcollat' => 'PXW_CYRL', //беше празно
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I tried changing char_set and collation also changed `$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';` with windows-1251 and nothing.

Thank you for your time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149653/discussion-on-question-by-pa4o-empty-like-query-with-non-latin-letters-in-live).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem with MySQL was this line:

```
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci'
```

Now it works:

```
'dbcollat' => ''
```

The problem with Firebird with Cyrillic search is caused by the database charset 'NONE'.